# Titanium Studio app crashes while swiping the tabs?

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am developing android app using Titanium Studio 3.2.1, I have tabs to change the screens while I am moving one tab to other tab I am getting below error,

```
**[ERROR] :  SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length**
```

what is this mean? why I am getting this?

and my issue is I able to move tabs one time only, again I am trying to return to the tabs app getting crash.

will any one please suggest me out to out of this issue?

I gone thorough this link but I am didn't understand what I have to do, I am new to titanium?

http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/38-titanium-mobile/140-titanium-mobile-dynamic-tabgroups-on-android

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this, I run my app using Titanium SDK as 3.1.3 in MAC OS, it is running fine without crashing.

but still have some doubts in titanium studio.

Why not in Titanium SDK : 3.2.1 ?
Why not in Windows OS.?

Any ways my answer will helps for someone

Thanks